# How to create circular sections?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, graphics2d

IDE: Visual studio 2010, c# .net 4.0 winforms application.

Hi, In my application I have to divide a Circle(which is set on a panel(circular image) in 8 sections please suggest how to divide that in 8 sections.

**Example**
[image: Example]

Because I want to perform different mouse down mouse up events on these sections. So It will be better if you can suggest any trick way or algorithm or dll or api to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is best expressed in polar coordinates, while mouse coordinates are typically given as cartesian values.

To convert, calculate in what part of your control the mouse is, as a coordinate offset.
E.g.,

```
var xOffset = xMouse - xCenter;
var yOffset = yMouse - yCenter;
```

Use [atan2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to turn the offsets into an angle in [0, 360] deg:

```
var angle = Math.Atan2(yOffset, xOffset)/Math.Pi*180 + 180;
```

Now use the angle value to determine what sector you are in:

```
int nSectors = 8;
int sectorId = (int)angle/360.0*nSectors;
```

Comment: Very nice, What is the name of this algorithm..?

Comment: Well, I guess it's too short to deserve to be called an algorithm, but it's the typical conversion from cartesian to polar coordinates.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system, 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html

Comment: `Atan2()` needs the arguments reversed.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the (x,y) coordinates into polar coordinate (radius,angle) from the center of the circle. Then if radius is inside the circle, use the angle value to figure out which segment the user clicked in.

For example if the center of the circle is located at `(xc,yc)` and a click occurs in `(x,y)` then

```
float dx = x-xc, dy = y-yc;
float radius = (float)Math.Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(dy,dx);
if(angle<0) { angle += 2*Math.PI; }
float segment_angle = 2*Math.PI/8;

if( radius <= diameter/2)
{
    int segment = (int)(angle/segment_angle);
}
```

Comment: I added a check for negative angles.